# An array of pointers to 2d arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

I was assigned a mission to create some kind of tic-tac-toe game, in which the player can reverse the game by inputing a negative number of the amount of turns he wants to take the game back in time.
And so, I figured i'd need to save each turn of the game in some kind of array that I could then later on approach if I need to.

To sum it up, I need to declare an array of pointers to 2d arrays, and I have no clue how to do that.
Heres the code:[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQTEi.png)
if I guessed it right and it is the way of declaring it, can u find any way that it would not work?

Comment: 1) Always tag a language ([tag:c]?). 2) [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Event source, save the exact instructions of every move in an collection, index the collection -2

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
    // something here, probably...
    int     field[N][N]; // or something similar
    Player  turn;        // whose turn it is now?
    // any other data you need
} Board;

Board   gameHistory[100];  // array of Board, fixed-size
// or ...
Board*  gameHistory;       // points into an array of Board, any size
// or ...
Board*  gameHistory[100];  // array of pointers to Board, fixed size
// or ...
Board** gameHistory;       // points into an array of pointers to Board, any size
```

Look ma, no pointers to 2D arrays!

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*arr[M])[N][N];
```

is what you ask for, but I am quite sure it is not what you actually need

Comment: what does this array do?

Comment: i want an array that each of its pointers is basically a 2 d array so if i write arr[i]- it will be a 2d array of [N][N]

Comment: @RavidOfek, so maybe 3d array will suit you needs `int A[M][N][N];`?

Comment: it works, thnx, but i dont understand why